# How to search hierarchy level category with comma separated?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a category tree with limitless sub-categories in the same table which can be differentiated with parent_id.
[image]

For now, when i try to search in search box this is how result are displayed.
[image: Category Search Box]

Now i want to search with comma separated like "Non Veg Restaurant , Diyalo Foodland Chitwan, Non veg Curries" then only display that particular result like.
***Non Veg Restaurant | Diyalo Foodland Chitwan | Non veg Curries***

```
$search = explode(',',$keyword);
            if(isset($search[0]))
            {
                $category = $category->where(function($q) use ($search){
                    $query = $q;
                    if(isset($search[0]))
                    {
                        $query = $query->whereRaw("LOWER(CONCAT_WS('', title,description)) LIKE LOWER('%".pg_escape_string(trim($search[0]))."%')");  
                    }
                    if(isset($search[1]))
                    {
                        $query = $query->whereRaw("LOWER(CONCAT_WS('', title,description)) LIKE LOWER('%".pg_escape_string(trim($search[1]))."%')");  
                    }
                    if(isset($search[2]))
                    {
                        $query = $query->whereRaw("LOWER(CONCAT_WS('', title,description)) LIKE LOWER('%".pg_escape_string(trim($search[2]))."%')");  
                    }
                    return $query;
                });
            }
```

Comment: Do you want to do it on backend or frontend? Please share some code so we can help you better. I think your search is working but you should change your frontend

Comment: @gguney i want to do it on backend

Comment: Okay this is your search code but there is no show part. Where is it concatane the data? I think it can be in your frontend.

Comment: @gguney i just concatenated the parent title in the frontend part